# java parse binary file and convert to hex

Tags: java, binary, hex

**Please read my question carefully, then judge if it is duplicate**

**I am green. If there is any mistake in my description please help me figure it out**

I want to parse a binary file by java. the first pic is the file opened by hex editor, you can see from 000000 0 to 000000 3 is **ef ef ef ef**

[image]

here is my code

```
String filepath = "D:\\CHR_2_20151228132500.dat.gz";
File file = new File(filepath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(fis);

DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(gzip);

byte[] bytes = new byte[20];

din.read(bytes, 0, 4);

for (byte b : bytes) {
    String str  = Integer.toHexString(b);
    System.out.print(str);
}
```

this is the result I parse you can see there is **ffffff** between each **ef**  and several zero appended

[image]

I want get data as same as it in hex editor.how can I get this ?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here: post the text; and don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str  = Integer.toHexString(b);
```

Bytes are signed in Java. You need:

```
String str  = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff);
```

And then to ensure two digits you need:

```
String str  = Integer.toHexString((b & 0xff)+256).substring(1);
```